# The textbook's natural deduction proof for $\vdash(\neg(\phi\to\psi)\to\phi)$ seems to be wrong with regard to RAA(Reductio Ad Absurdum).

Tags: logic, proof-verification, proof-explanation, natural-deduction, sequent-calculus

As you can see below, $\psi$ pops out of nowhere due to RAA(reductio ad absurdum). This is probably wrong. Is there really a proper natural deduction proof for $\vdash(\neg(\phi\to\psi)\to\phi)$?

[image]

Update 1 : I added another example.

[image]

Comment: why do you think it is wrong ? to prove that $\lnot(a \implies b)$ you have to prove first that "$a$ is a theorem" and then that "$\lnot b$ is a theorem"

Comment: @user1952009 You're saying that the sequent is correct, and it is correct. But, my question is about the correctness of the proof of the sequent.

Comment: It is correct; again "discharging" is not mandatory: the "meaning" of the RAA rule is: "form a contradiction, you can derive anything". In particular, you can derive $\psi$ discharging a previous occurrence of $\lnot \psi$.

Comment: In most cases (see [Natural Deduction](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4)) there are two different rule : ($\bot$E) : $\bot \vdash \psi$ and ($\lnot$E) (or: RAA) : "if $\Gamma, \lnot \psi \vdash \bot$, then $\Gamma \vdash \psi$.

Comment: The book is definitely not friendly to self learners.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA It seems that deriving $\phi$ from only $\bot$ is not RAA. Why do you think $(\bot E)$ is the same as RAA?

Comment: Ok - ($\bot$E) : $\bot \vdash \psi$ and *RAA* are **not** the same rule: the first one is *intuistionistically* valid while *RAA* is not. But **if** you are usung Chiswell & Hodges, they do not consider intuitionsitic logic, but only the classical one: thus, they do introduce only *RAA* and in this case ($\bot$E) is subsumed under it.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I'm using Chiswell & Hodges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is correct. From $\bot$ you can infer anything, which is why the $\psi$ is allowed to "pop out of nowhere" in the first use of RAA in the proof.  Note that this use of RAA does not discharge any hypotheses (there is no number next to the line that infers $\psi$ from $\bot$).

In the second use of RAA in the proof, from $\bot$ we discharge hypothesis 2 ($\neg \phi$) in order to infer $\phi$.  Perhaps this is a more normal-looking use of RAA that you are used to (if $\neg \phi$ yields a contradiction, then infer $\phi$).

Comment: I think if I inferred $\psi$ from $\bot$ without assuming and discharding $\not\psi$, then RAA doesn't seem to fit. It looks like some other deduction rule.

Comment: You can always introduce a $\neg \psi$ assumption right at the point of application, then immediately discharge it to conclude $\psi$.

Comment: How exactly would I do it in a natural deduction proof? Can you show me a picture?

Comment: In a natural deduction proof, you're allowed to introduce any assumption at any time (as in 1,2,3 in your example).  At the point where you've concluded $\bot$, introduce an assumption $\neg \psi$.  Then immediately conclude $\psi$, discharging the assumption.

Comment: I can't imagine it well by textual descriptions. Do you mean I can derive $\psi$ as in the second image of the question by introducing $\neg\psi$ next to $\bot$? I just added a second image to my question.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.